# Handling state of website with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a chat that heavily relies on JavaScript and which uses node.js for the backend. I'd like to do as much as possible in JavaScript (maybe even no PHP at all if possible). One of the problems I ran into is how to hold the state of the site. When a user clicks on a contact the content of the communication is fetched from the server.

What would you suggest to save the id of the currently displayed contact. Anchor? Variable? Cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are used for a relatively long-term usage by your website, specifically when you want to keep some data client-side which was custom-tailored for the user at hand (and doesn't jeopardize your system). So, when he (or she) revisits your website, it will be as they left it - without you storing unnecessary per-user data in the database. So, from the *definition*, that's a no for cookies.

Your problem is more of an immediate-usage nature - you're working with the id of a currently displayed contact and that is perhaps best suited for a variable (from the offered), or perhaps even the DOM - as jfriend00 pointed out.

And, a piece of general advice, do consider standard security implications and code defensively.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this state for the duration of the page, then there's no reason to use a cookie.  Plus cookies are somewhat limited in both size and qty.

So, it's really up to you whether you want to save the data in a javascript variable or just put it in the DOM and access it directly in the DOM whenever you need it.  I tend to keep high level things in javascript variables to make it quick to carry out future tasks, but don't see any reason to duplicate lots of data by storing in both DOM and JS variable if that data is in the DOM.

But, in the end, it depends on what type of data it is, what is being stored in the DOM already, what type of future access to the data you need and what actions you're taking on it.  We'd need to know a bit more about the details of what you're doing to offer more concrete advice for your specific circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Between those 3 options, I would suggest **storing it in a variable**. Here's why:

- Cookies aren't easily accessible with plain javascript, at least not without the addition of a few custom functions
- Tying data to the view (ie the `id` to an `<a>` anchor tag), while common, breaks from clean coding conventions. It sets you up for headaches down the road, as i've learned through experience.

Using variables or other persistent data stores (ie `localStorage`) are better ways to store your data. If you're looking for a great way to organize the data and views in your javascript app, check out the [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) framework.